# What is MAC spoofing in the internet connections manager and does it have any benefit in terms of security?

Tags: networking, security, cloning

What is MAC spoofing in the internet connections and does it have any benefit in terms of security?

What is the purpose of cloning the mac or spoofing it?

Does it help protect against hackers at all?

Comment: By the way I already have the Ubuntu security guide and know all the other methods I just don't know anything about this and what purpose it has.  I alwasys secure my systems as much as possible so I wonder if it has any benefit - can anyone explain what its for?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu.com :-) Please add new info to your question by editing it. It will be visible in the previews then and improves the readability. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

MAC spoofing is what you do when you tell your NIC (Network Interface Card, which can be wireless too) to use a different address for communication on the local network (the segment before the first router).

This MAC address is not (at least with IPv4) visible on the outside, so you will not gain any security from spoofing it.

The main reason for spoofing the MAC address is that some ISPs tie their equipment to one MAC address (sometimes they don't want to allow several computer within your network) - in that case you **can** advertise the MAC-address already registered with them from another system.

The second reason for using it: Owners of WiFi-systems often restrict access to their system to some "whitelisted" MAC addresses. In that case it is *possible* but **illegal** to use a spoofed MAC address to gain access to that WiFi.

Comment: It is possible to see the MAC i have used aircrack-ng in monitor mode andi see everyones mac addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Mac addresses can be useful in setting up certain network configurations. Mac addresses are individual to devices, ie network cards and can be used to filter allowed connections in a network.

One example of use would be in the use of a WAP. A WAP can be setup to rebroadcast, or repeat the information from another WAP, typically identified to each other by their individual Mac Addresses.

If you set your wireless devices up to only accept connections from white listed mac addresses, it is possible to use “spoofing” to gain a connection to your router anyways, but would require that the individual have identified one of the mac addresses which are white listed ahead of time.

You can find more information on this topic here: https://perot.me/mac-spoofing-what-why-how-and-something-about-coffee

Comment: While that link may contain valuable information, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the contents here, and provide the link for reference.